# Maintaining Privacy at OSNs in Fabric 1.0

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Is it true that the OSNs can see all the transactions payload (all the transactions data)? And does OSNs should be trusted organizations only? Is there a way to main privacy at OSNs?

I have three ordering nodes hosted by three different organizations. A peer is free to choose any of them. But the issue is it seems like the ordering nodes see everything that happening in the network. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes OSNs can see all the transaction data. So OSNs can only be trusted organizations or organizations who are allowed to see everything that's happening in the network.

Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 developers are working on a way to avoid this. You can track the fix here https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-1151